# Xcode 7 SVN Check Out browser

Tags: ios, iphone, svn, xcode7

When going to Source Control -> Check Out:

In Xcode 5 and 6, I used to be able to get a repository browser by adding a slash "/" at the end of the repository location. If you didn't include the slash it would try to download everything in that repository, but including it would give a file explorer so you could select just the project/folder you wanted to check out.

I'm really struggling to find something similar in xcode 7. With or without the slash at the end it tries to download the entire repository, instead of allowing me to select the project I want.

Additionally, I can't get it to checkout any specific project in SVN. I enter a location that exists. Then I get a pop up that says it can't find a repo at the location, but the location inside the quotes doesn't include the last character of the location I entered.

**How can I get a file/repository browser in Xcode 7 like in the previous versions when checking out a project from SVN?**